# Insert User through Sharepoint batch send HTTP Request Connector

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I need to insert items into sharepoint by using SP connector - Send HTTP Request
I send body :  `"User": { "Key": "i:0#.f|membership|@{first(body('Get_by_mail')?['value'])['Email']}" },`
Despite it having successfully created, the sharepoint shows the field without value. Do you have any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to make this work using the below JSON in the body while sending the HTTP request.

```
{    
"__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.<YOUR_LIST_NAME>ListItem" },    
"Title": "ccc",    
"UserId": 6
}
```

UserId is the key which represents the column in my Sharepoint which is named as User. Consider if Person is the column in your Sharepoint then make sure you set the key value as PersonId.

[image]

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your JSON:

```
"User": 
{ 
    "Key": "i:0#.f|membership|@{first(body('Get_by_mail')?['value'])['Email']}"
}
```

you'll notice that you're sending just a key to a key/value pair target.  The item inserts because a Key is provided, but it doesn't display anything because you did not provide a Value that would be displayed.  Try the following JSON instead:

```
    "User": 
{ 
    "Key": "i:0#.f|membership|@{first(body('Get_by_mail')?['value'])['Email']}",
    "Value": "i:0#.f|membership|@{first(body('Get_by_mail')?['value'])['Email']}"
}
```